# Is there a general way to prove inequalities where equality holds when the variables are equal?

Tags: inequality

I see a lot of inequalities like $a^2+b^2+c^2≥ab+cb+ca$ or $a^4+b^4+c^4≥a^2b^2+a^2c^2+b^2c^2$ where the "total" power on both sides is the same but it's just been split between different variables. For example, in the inequality $a^2b^2+b^2c^2+a^2c^2≥a^2bc+b^2ac+c^2ab$, the side that has been "de-homogenised", like the powers that have been split between more variables seems to always be the lower than if all the powers were concentrated on one term. So my question is, is this just a coincidence or  is there some sort of reasoning to why spreading the variables decreases the value and secondly, is there a general sort of way I can try to approach all inequalities where the powers have been split?

Comment: Indeed, there is an inequality that generalises all of those: Muirhead's inequality: (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muirhead%27s_inequality )